# Accessing Details View Bind Data Before The View Is Rendered

Tags: asp.net

I have a field in a details view shown below

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="DTMON_F" HeaderText="Monday Hours From: " InsertVisible="False"
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="HOURS" Visible="false" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Monday Hours From: " SortExpression="HOURS">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <uc1:TimePicker ID="tpMondayHours" runat="server"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
               <%-- <uc1:TimePicker runat="server" ID="tpMondayHours" />--%>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtMondayHours" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DTMON_F") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblMondayHours" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DTMON_F") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Before "DTMON_F" is binded to the view I want to cut the string that is returned...Where and how might I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `OnDataBinding` event for each control instead of doing the bind inline.  This will give you the ability to do whatever you like with the data before assigning it to the control.

Example using your `Label`.  The same could be applied to the `TextBox`:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMondayHours" runat="server"
    OnDataBinding="lblMondayHours_DataBinding"></asp:Label>

protected void lblMondayHours_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)(sender);
    string yourValue = (int)(Eval("DTMON_F"));
    // *** Do whatever you want with the value now
    lbl.Text = yourValue;
}
```

Comment: What if I have 14 of these labels to do? Can I consolidate the code somehow or will I have to make a seperate event for each label?